# Removing '\xa0' characters from string without Unicode conversion in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I am trying to remove `\xa0` (non-breaking spaces) from a Python 2 string without doing any Unicode conversion.  I tried replacing these characters using:

```
s = s.replace('\xa0', ' ')
```

After the replacement, when I copied my string into Sublime Text, a new problematic, weird-looking character appeared: `DEC 65533, HEX 0xfffd, BYTE b'\\ufffd'`

What's going on here and does it make sense for me to not want to cast my `str` to `unicode` (and back)?

Comment: must be at the start I presume. looks like a Byte Order Mark: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: How did you copy into sublime text? Maybe the system clipboard converts the data into utf8 (and adds a BOM)? What makes you suspect this is caused by removing the non-breaking spaces?

Comment: If this is related to copy-paste, it's platform specific (which is true for many text-encoding issues). So you should add information to the question about the which operating system / distro you are using.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not a bad idea - I'll check.  If this is the case, the BOM is appearing in the middle of the string.

Comment: @HåkenLid I'm on Windows. The character does not appear until I remove the non-breaking spaces.  My XML parser (ElementTree) is complaining about an invalid character regardless of the copy/paste.

Comment: probably heuristic encoding detection of the editor.

Comment: `s = s.replace('\xc2\xa0', ' ')` looks like it fixed the issue, but I'm not entirely sure why this works over `s = s.replace('\xa0', ' ')`.

Comment: `'\xc2\xa0'` is `u'\xa0'` encoded as UTF-8.  Replacing `'\xa0'` leaves `'\xc2'`, which is garbage.